# Chaining a method on dynamic call

Tags: java, spring-boot

Supposed I have a User list on `Post entity`

```
private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
```

and I can clear it using

```
post.getUsers().clear();
```

and can add to it with

```
post.getUsers().addAll(Something);
```

how can I do the same if use to call the function `getUsers` dynamically? I tried

```
post.getClass().getMethod("getUsers").invoke(post).getClass().getMethod("clear").invoke(new ArrayList<>());
```

and also I tried

```
ArrayList.class.getMethod("clear").invoke(post);
```

but im getting a

```
WARN  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class]
```

Any idea on how can  I do it?

take note that this is working

```
post.getClass().getMethod("getUsers").invoke(post); //get the users
```

I just have no idea how can I chained the clear method or the addAll on it.

Comment: can you show how?

Comment: should pass Array list object returned from return of get users function for the invoke of clear function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Method.invoke](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-) returns an `Object` and the `Object`  class does not have a `clear()` method, so you need to cast the returned object into a `List`.

```
Post post = new Post();
Method m = post.getClass().getMethod("getUsers");
List<User> users = (List<User>)m.invoke(post);
users.clear();
```

And if you want it in one line, it is ugly, but can be done:

```
((List<User>)(post.getClass().getMethod("getUsers").invoke(post))).clear();
```

This also works:

```
List.class.cast(post.getClass().getMethod("getUsers").invoke(post)).clear();
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply where having a holiday. How can I use it on addAll? I tried this List.class.cast(getMethodEntity).addAll((Collection<?>) Objects.requireNonNull(fieldValue)); this is working but im having a warning saying that Unchecked call to 'addAll(Collection<? extends E>)' as a member of raw type 'java.util.List'

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59241734/java-list-cast-to-be-able-to-use-addall-function

Comment: @Beginner This is because the list you get from `invoke` has no type. 
When you try to add a `User`, you have a warning, and it basically telling you: "Watch out, you are trying to add a `User` to a `List`, and I can't know if that List is a `List<User>`". You know it is a `List<User>` so you can ignore that warning, or suppress it using an annotation. I don't think there is a way around that. It is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the JavaDocs of `ArrayList`.

`ArrayList.clear()` returns nothing because it's a `void` method, `ArrayList.addAll()` returns a `boolean`.

So to allow for method chaining, you'd have to wrap the calls in your Post entity to return the post entity itself. Then you could get method chaining.

So, in your Post entity, you'd add:

```
public Post clearUsers() {
    users.clear();
    return this;
}
```

and

```
public Post addAllUsers(List<User> usersToAdd) {
    users.addAll(usersToAdd);
    return this;
}
```

and invoke these methods instead of `getUsers().xyz()` (which is very bad style anyway. The posobject owns these users. it should be the only one to manipulate these).

Comment: what do you mean by wrap. sorry im just new to java

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke those methods on the array list object contained by `post`.

For example, you can call `clear` on `post.getUsers()` as

```
ArrayList.class.getMethod("clear").invoke(
                // this will give you reference to array list contained by post
                post.getClass().getMethod("getUsers").invoke(post)
        );
```

Tested above code as following

```
public class DynamicInvocation {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Post post = new Post();
        post.getUsers().add(new User());
        System.out.println(post.getUsers());
        ArrayList.class.getMethod("clear").invoke(
                post.getClass().getMethod("getUsers").invoke(post)
        );
        System.out.println(post.getUsers());
    }
}

class Post {
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
}

class User {
}
```

Comment: still the same Im getting the error object is not an instance of declaring class

Comment: @Beginner added the invocation example which works fine. Could you check your code once again?